# Possible unintended reference comparison issue when trying to find a value in hashtable

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, hashtable

May I know what the wrong I've done here :

```
Hashtable  dd = new Hashtable () ;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            dd.Add(i, i.ToString());
        }

var  key = dd.Values.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault(s => dd[s] == "10000");
```

it keep showing the following error:

```
possible unintended reference comparison to get a value
comparison cast the left hand to string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hashtable` is not a generic type, and therefore the return of `dd[s]` is an `object`. When you use `==` and either side is an `object` at compile time, you get a reference comparison, not a value comparison. This is because all operators are `static` and bound by the compiler, and the `==` in `object` performs referential comparisons.

To fix this, use the virtual `.Equals`, which look up the correct method at run-time

```
dd[s].Equals("10000")
```

Or `object.Equals`, which checks for `null` and then calls the virtual `.Equals`

```
object.Equals(dd[s], "1000000")
```

Note this is only a warning, *not* an error, and your code will compile, though likely have unexpected results.

If you can use a more up to date class, however, it may prove far more powerful to use the generic form of `Hashtable`, [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**: as a final note, your code may not work even after applying `.Equals`, becuase by using [`dd[s]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you're making a key lookup, but passing in a value instead.

Comment: `dd[s].Equals("10000")` make no sense due to the `NullValue`. `object.Equals(dd[s], "1000000")`  looks good to me. However, how to involve it in`var key = dd.Values.OfType<int>().FirstOrDefault(s => ?????)`

Comment: You would not use `d.Values.OfType<int>` because the values are, in this case, always `string`. If you want to look up a key by value, you have to do it by iterating through the collection such as via `var key = dd.Keys.Select(k => new { Key = k, Value = dd[k] }).FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Value.Equals("10000")).Key;`

Comment: Did not work. Can you edit it please ?
I want to find the first match and exit the sub in order to calculate the time of finding an item in `Hashtable`

Comment: If you're looking for timing, there is a _huge_ difference between looking up by value (which will be at best about as fast as any looking through a nonkeyed collection like `List<T>`), and look up by key (which is what `HashTable` and `Dictionary<...>` are designed to do)

Answer (score 1):

`Hashtable` is an old structure, which you should avoid using. It doesn't use *generics*, so any object you get out of it is an `object`.

When you compare `dd[s]` to `"10000"` with an `==` operator, it will use a reference comparison (e.g. do the two `object`s refer to the same point in memory), whereas you *probably* intend for *any* string matching `"10000"` to come out equal. The compiler is warning you that this probably won't give you what you want.